# vscode find tab to always go to files to include

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm using find in file and after I finish typing the search query I typically want to filter by file type. If I press tab it automatically goes to match case, match whole words and regex options first, and only on the 4th tab ends up in files to include. Any way to make it go straight to files to include on the first tab?

Comment: I think the best you can do is Ctrl+DownArrow to `search.focus.nextInputBox`.  Two times to get to `files to include`.  And Ctrl+UpArrow for the previous inputBox.

Comment: @Mark If you put that as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best you can do is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> to trigger the command `search.focus.nextInputBox`. Two times to get to `files to include`.

And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd> for the `previousInputBox`.